# Trouble loading earthengine-api in rgee R package

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, rgee

I have succesfully installed and loaded rgee. When I run ee_check() sometimes it does work and returns **✔ [Ok] earthengine-api** and sometimes it does not work and returns **✔ [X] earthengine-api not installed**.

I alwasys follow the same steps:

> library(reticulate)

> library(rgee)

> ee_check()

I have no clue why it is so arbitrary

Does someone have the same issue or know the reason for this?

Many thanks in advance